# Передать переменную из js в smarty аргументом функции

Tags: php, smarty

нужно передать js переменную в качестве аргумента smarty функции, вроде такого

```
<script>
    var test = 1;
    {$controller->function(<И ЗДЕСЬ НУЖНО ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ ИЗ JS>)}
</script>
```

Возможно ли это? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, это невозможно, т. к. шаблон Smarty исполняется (рендерится) на сервере до того, как браузер, который получил этот шаблон, выполнит javascript.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду извращаться)

Comment: Может что подскажете? Функция у меня генерирует опшены для селекта с выбранным элементом, значение которого передано как раз этим аргументом. Может получать все опшены без выборки активного, а потом делать выбранный через js?

Comment: Да, если "решение" для выбора определённого option'а принимается на клиенте, то и выбирать его нужно на клиенте. А на основе каких данных он выбирается на js?

Comment: На основе данных, которые выбрал пользователь в предыдущем поле

Comment: Да, раз вся механика происходит на клиенте (в браузере пользователя), соответственно действия должны осуществляться на js